# Eigen matrix right division equivalent

Tags: c++, eigen

in Matlab if I write

```
A = B*inv(C)
```

(with A, B and C being square matrices), I get a warning that matrix inversion should be replaced with a matrix "right-division" (due to being numerically more stable and accurate) like

```
A = B/C
```

In my Eigen C++ project I have the following code:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double> A = B*(C.inverse());
```

and I was woundering if there is an equivalent replacement for taking the matrix inverse in Eigen analogous to the one in Matlab mentioned above?

I know that matrix "left-division" can be expressed by solving a system of equations for expressions like

```
A = inv(C)*B
```

but what about

```
A = C*inv(B)
```

in Eigen?

Comment: You could transpose everything to end up with the same form. Not sure if it will be more performant than calculating the inverse, though.

Comment: taking inverse of large matrix is inefficient way of solving `AxC=B` or `CxA=B` matrix equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the most efficient way to do this is to rewrite your equation to

```
A^T = inv(C^T) * B^T
A   = (inv(C^T) * B^T)^T
```

which can be implemented in Eigen as

```
SomeDecomposition decompC(C);  // decompose C with a suiting decomposition
Eigen::MatrixXd A = decompC.transpose().solve(B.transpose()).transpose();
```

There [were/are plans](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=99#c48), that eventually, one can write

```
A = B * decompC.inverse();
```

and Eigen will evaluate this in the most efficient way.